# How to rollback a map to a previous state

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I died in lava with resources. How can I rollback the map to what it was 1 minute ago?

P.S: I am looking at the death screen. I can post screenshots if needed.

Comment: I put a bet on you can't, I have never see this being done. The only way is to do a roll back but for this you would have needed to have saved a previous version of your map; If you die in lava, that's the game, just do another stuff and get go more ressources.

Comment: There is no way to do this. You just have to go to your previous save.

Answer (score 3):

If it happened in your solo map then there is no way you can do a rollback of the map.

I suggest in the future that you set up a local server and add some plugins to avoid this kind of problems. 
Some plugin make automatic saves/backups of the map like [PerfectBackup](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/perfect-backup/).
(for 1.9)

Comment: Exactly. If you haven't been taking backups, then there's nothing to rollback to. OP can either get the resources again and be more careful (like bringing a bucket of water, not digging straight down), or spawn the items they had in with a command/mcedit.

Answer (score -1):

***You can now save with /save, by downloading mods or plugins, can be run in Singleplayer and can be run in Multiplayer too. Save it first, then you can roll back when you want with /rollback. Autosaving is also added. You can autosave with /autosave enable or /autosave disable. It saves each 5 minute.***